# TVRage consume service via AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to consume this webservice (http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/show_list.php) from TVRage using Angularjs.

I can 'connect' to the service (using firebug I see GET show_list.php STATUS 200 OK) but when i try to print any data from the response I get none.

This is the code that i use:

```
var TV_Episodes = angular.module('TV_Episodes', ['ngResource']);

TV_Episodes.controller('GetAllEpisodes', function($scope, $resource) {
    var dataService = $resource('http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/show_list.php');
    $scope.data = dataService.get();
    console.log($scope.data());
});
```

any ideas on how I can just console.log the the response?

**UPDATE 1:**

After some more trying i found out that that i get the following error as a response from TVRAGE.

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/show_list.php`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://localhost`' is therefore not allowed access."

therefor i tweaked my code so

```
var dataService = $resource('http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/show_list.php?key=xxxx',{},{headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }});
```

but i still get the same error as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *get* method is asyncronous.  When it is called it returns immediately with a reference to an object (or array, if specified - but not a promise as indicated in MWay's answer).  Then, later, that same reference is updated with the data that is returned from the server on success.  Here's the [relevant part](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) from the documentation:

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering, once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the new data. This means that in most cases one never has to write a callback function for the action methods.

As fast as the request might be, it won't resolve until the event loop comes around again.  The resource is helpfully designed to free you up from having to worry about writing callbacks.  If you need to though, the *get* method takes callback function parameters that will be invoked when the request resolves and the data is ready.

```
var TV_Episodes = angular.module('TV_Episodes', ['ngResource']);

TV_Episodes.controller('GetAllEpisodes', function($scope, $resource) {
    var dataService = $resource('http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/show_list.php');
    $scope.data = dataService.get(function () {
        console.log($scope.data());
    });
});
```

Or, you can access the *promise* used for processing the request by using *$promise", which is a property on empty instance object returned from *get*.

Answer (score 1):

`$resource.get()` returns a promise, which means you are likely printing to the console prior to the data being retrieved. Instead use the appropriate callback function:

```
$scope.data = dataService.get(function() { console.log($scope.data); });
```

Comment: I replaced my code with your snippet but I still cant see the data in the console. I jsut get a "GET http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/show_list.php 200OK 249ms".

Comment: Are you able to setup a fiddle?